# Positioning div elements left & top not working with content in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've got a webpage with a full-screen canvas. Over the canvas I'm going to place and position divs that will contain UI elements for the canvas. I'm using jQuery to create the divs and give them the css style they need. I also re-position and/or re-size them in JavaScript upon window re-size. The problem is, as soon as I enter even one space into a div, FireFox says 'NO!' and seems to ignore any css changes made by JavaScript, even if I remove the content of the div again.

Here's some technical details:

The div I'll show is a fullscreen div that overlays the canvas and functions as dim-screen in case there are dialogs the user has opened so the canvas appears darker and extra attention is pulled towards the dialog.

The css I'm using is:

```
.ui_layer {
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}

#ui_layer_dim {
    background-color: #000000;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

In JavaScript I have my own function that creates the div, but it runs this jQuery:

```
$("<div id='ui_layer_dim' class='ui_layer' style='z-index:1'/>");
```

Then, on onWindowResize (tiggered by a window 'resize' eventlistener), I change the div's width and height to fit the new window size:

```
gameUI.layers["ui_layer_dim"].onWindowResize = function() {
    this.css("width", window.innerWidth + "px");
    this.css("height", window.innerHeight + "px");
};
```

In Chrome this works perfectly, even if I place content in the div. FireFox works, but only when the div is in it's initial state. One change to the div's contents and 'BOOM it goes': No more dynamic sizing.

I've tried the different css position settings, tried setting the width and height attributes using the css function, using the style function of the element and using setAttribute to see if it's caused by some sort of incompatibility; the results didn't change.

I've run a series of tests to see what happens to the html as soon as content is placed into the div and noticed something weird: The inspector and css rules won't show changes to the width and height of the window's innerWidth and innerHeight. Neither does the div itself, but I've set up some logging to view info about the window's innerWidth and innerHeight before setting the div's width and height and some logging about the div's width and height after setting it, and that actually shows the correct dimensions...

After building and testing the system for several days I have no clue anymore what could cause the problem. Like I've said before: Chrome works as it should so I know my code technically works, but it might just be that a different approach is needed to make it work in FireFox. I hope anyone knows. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Here's a fiddle with the code, try running in FireFox, resize the result, it should resize the grey div as well. Now, right click the result, go to the inspector and put some text or even a space inside the div and resize again. Not working for me. Link: http://jsfiddle.net/UsLL6/

Edit 2: Here's a screenshot that will hopefully clear up the problem I'm having. Marked yellow is the initial state of the browser width, I set it to very narrow to be able to show the problem more clearly. Marked orange is the state after I made the browser wider a bit. You can see the grey div doesn't resize with it as it should, neither do the inspector value and the CSS rules value, but the console shows the correct value. The first ("Setting property:.....") was retrieved from window.innerWidth, the second ("Property height now has....") was retrieved from the actual width property from the div element using style.getPropertyValue.
[image]

Just noticed IE gives the same result as FireFox, but yea..IE....

Comment: please fiddle your code.

Comment: It's sometimes helpful to isolate the problematic section of your code. It can make you see errors a bit better and possibly realize that it's actually working correctly, now that you've isolated it from all of the other code. http://Jsfiddle.net can be very helpful with that.

Comment: Should've fiddled it in the first place! Working on that right now!

Comment: Just added the fiddle, dunno if there's notifications for edits so just letting you know. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you need that space there. If you create the div with a space to begin with http://jsfiddle.net/UsLL6/2/ it seems to be bulletproof to strange behavior when you edit and resize it later on. At least in my tests. ||| You should comment with, for example @ProllyGeek to ping a person when commenting. If you are commenting on someone's answer, you don't have to use the @ symbol.

Comment: @Joonas It's not about the space, it's about **any content**. For the UI I'll be placing HTML elements into these divs. I've tried the link you posted and it gives me the same result as before.

Comment: Yyeaa, I don't know why I thought that was working... cause looking at it now, it totally isn't || It looks like `htmlObject` gets the updated dimensions in console, while the actual dom element does not... http://jsfiddle.net/UsLL6/3/ || I haven't been able to wrap my head around that. Although, couldn't you just use css to make that happen? http://jsfiddle.net/8nqrg/ ...or most of it anyways?

Comment: @Joonas In the case with the dim-layer, yes, but that would become a lot more difficult when working with positioned user interface elements. I've tried doing that with css before trying it this way and that just got way too complicated with making dynamic UI elements and all the different layers coming into play. I'm afraid I might not have another choice though.

Comment: Ok just noticed something I should have noticed long before: When adding and removing content from the div dynamically it seems to work. I don't know if FireFox is just going Math.Random on me or if this result is expected. I'll check again next week to see if it's as stable as I hope it is. Even though the problem might not exist for me anymore I'm still very confused by the fact that editing the div in the FF inspector creates such a weird result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding and removing content from the div using JavaScript it works. Even though the problem does not exist for me anymore I'm still very confused by the fact that editing the div in the FF inspector creates such a weird result.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `gameUI.layers` known by mozilla?
Did you try the jQuery solution?

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
      $('#ui_layer_dim').width(window.innerWidth);
      $('#ui_layer_dim').height(window.innerHeight);
  });
```

Comment: I tried the jQuery solution: Same result. I also checked the gameUI variable and noticed it was undefined, but the code can definitely reach it since it creates the div and everything. Maybe FireFox's console uses a different location to launch code from? I've tried attaching gameUI to the window and that makes it reachable for the console, but the problem remains.